# Wrong API key for Xtify?

Tags: android, basic4android, xtify

I get this error message:

```
Caused by: com.xtify.android.sdk.InvalidFormatException: Could not read the api key. No meta data found in the manifest file.
at com.xtify.android.sdk.PersistentLocationManager.a( Unknown Source)
at com.xtify.android.sdk.PersistentLocationManager.c( Unknown Source)
at com.xtify.android.sdk.PersistentLocationManager.a( Unknown Source)
at com.xtify.android.sdk.PersistentLocationManager.<i nit>(Unknown Source)
at com.nejo.android.xtify.nejoXTIFY.initialize(nejoXT IFY.java:27)
at Xtracard.Customer.xti._service_create(xti.java:102 )
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at anywheresoftware.b4a.BA.raiseEvent2(BA.java:167)
... 13 more
```

This is in my manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name="com.nejo.android.xtify.NejoXtyreceiv er">
  <intent-filter androidriority="9999">
    <action android:name="com.xtify.android.sdk.SHOW_NOTIFICAT ION" />
    <!-- KEEP THE FORWARD SLASH IN FRONT OF THE APP KEY ON THE LINE BELOW -->
    <data android:scheme="notif" android:host="notification.xtify.com"
          androidathPrefix="/a0ef3978-dcb9-424d-9b03-1567f5814817" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The API key is correct. Xtifys support page throws an error when I ask them a question.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are the random spaces (like `<i nit>` and `NOTIFICAT ION`) actually in the stacktrace and manifest, or did you introduce them while formatting? (Oh yeah, and what's with `androidriority` in the manifest?)

Comment: I guess  this happened during formatting. The original:     <receiver android:name="com.nejo.android.xtify.NejoXtyreceiver">
- <intent-filter android:priority="9999">
  <action android:name="com.xtify.android.sdk.SHOW_NOTIFICATION" /> 
- <!--  KEEP THE FORWARD SLASH IN FRONT OF THE APP KEY ON THE LINE BELOW 
  --> 
  <data android:scheme="notif" android:host="notification.xtify.com" android:pathPrefix="/a0ef3978-dcb9-424d-9b03-1567f5814817" /> 
  </intent-filter>
  </receiver>

Comment: #1: What error on the xtify support page? I was just able to post a question without an issue.

#2: It looks like you're using an old/unsupported version of the Xtify SDK. Please upgrade to the latest GCM SDK. Full integration instructions are here: http://support.xtify.com/display/sdk/Getting+Started+with+Google+Cloud+Messaging

Comment: Thank you!
Now I was able to post the question to Xtify, they told me the same.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a third-party support question and should be asked elsewhere. 